# OctoberCMS belongsTo relationship saving problem

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I have two models:

- Brands
- Mods

I can display all brands via belongsTo function. Problem is when I try to save same brand two times, I get error duplicated entry.

This **belongsTo is causing duplicated entry error** when saving to DB two same brands.

> *Mods.php*

```
public $belongsTo = [  
  'brand' => [\Slasher\Farming\Models\Brands::class, 'key' => 'id'],    
  ];
```

This **belongsToMany works**, and save's data to DB, but is generating checkbox field (I only want to select one brand at one mod enty). I'm using pivot table for this relation.

> *Mods.php*

```
public $belongsToMany =[  
    'brand' =>[  
        'Slasher\Farming\Models\Brands',  
        'table' => 'slasher_farming_mods_brands',  
        'order' => 'brand_name'  
    ],  
];
```

**BelongsTo** example: (Brands are visible and I can save them. But problem is when saving same brand for more than two times).
[image]

Error I get when saving with belongsTo.

[image]

I tried also creating inverse relationships on Brands model with (belongsTo and belongsToMany), but still getting this error.

What type of relation should I make, to save Brands as dropdown list and to fix this duplicate error?

Comment: means you want a pivot table or just experimenting on it. and you want only a single dropdown to select brand only

Comment: I managed to find the problem. My mods table didn't have brand_id so I changed brand column to brand_id. And I have to remove key parameter from $belongsTo

Comment: 'brand' => ['Slasher\Farming\Models\Brands'] this works now.

Comment: actually, I just suggested it was not answer, you can post your correct code and mark it as an answer so it can be useful to others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with changing column in the mods name `brand` to `brand_id` and also changing belongsTo relation. I just removed key, and it works like a charm. No need for pivot table here.

> *Mods.php*

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'brand' => ['Slasher\Farming\Models\Brands']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pivot table for your relation, then you should use $belongsToMany. Pivot table is only used for many-to-many relations.

Comment: I tried to use pivot table only for testing purposes. I need belongsTo relation because I want to select only one brand at one mod.

Answer (score 0):

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: update `liam_blog_blogs` set `id` = 3, `liam_blog_blogs`.`updated_at` = 2022-07-26 09:30:09 where `id` = 2)"

Comment: It's not an answer, can you put this message into comment